# How to reuse same view controller in multiple container view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a container view in a view controller (lets say A) with an embed segue to a view controller (lets says B) which is in the same storyboard. Now the requirement is I have to use this same embedded view controller B in another container view in view controller C which is in different story board. Is it possible to reuse view controller B in multiple container views  ?

Comment: To embed B in C you might have to use `storyboard1.instantiateViewController(ViewControllerB.identifier) as! ViewControllerB`, setting data to show and delegate to call on B and set the containers‘ `displayViewController(viewController:)` or sth like that on the container to show it there. Nothing more is required to use a viewController in a container anywhere. Or you could go the Storyboard route..

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) For view controller B, add a storyboard identifier

[image]

2) Add a container view inside view controller C
[image]

3) Delete the view controller that is embedded to View Controller C

4) Add a "Storyboard Reference" next to view controller C, then drag from the container view inside view controller C to the storyboard reference and create an "Embed" segue

[image]

5) Select the storyboard reference and set the "Reference ID" to match view controller B's identifier. Also make sure "Storyboard" has the name of the storyboard that view controller B is in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can drag a `Storyboard Reference` in that `different storyboard`, and set it's `Storyboard` and `Referenced ID` properties to the `view controller B`.